# Handling multiple params in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a scenario where I have a form with adding new employees and deleting the saved employees in the same form. While adding it is fine but when we delete one record and click on save, it is throwing validation error in another page. I am trying to block in the same page as below is my controller method:

```
def check_params
  #raise
  return if params[:employee].present? 
  flash[:alert] = 'Please fill in form before submitting.'
  redirect_to edit_employee_url
end
```

I tried adding

```
return if params[:employee].present? && params[:employee][:emp_attributes]["0"]["_destroy"] != "1"
```

But works only for one employee record, if we had more than one record , it will not.

Below are the params captured through *raise*.

> > > params
> > >       => "✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>”AAABBBVC==",
> > >       "employee"=>{"emp_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"1", "name"=>"test",
> > >       "start_day_of_the_week"=>"Monday", "sw_id"=>"2"},
> > >       "1"=>{"name"=>"test2", "start_day_of_the_week"=>"Monday",
> > >       "sw_id"=>"3"}}}, "form_step"=>"2", "commit"=>"Save & Continue",
> > >       "view_context"=>:empdet, "controller"=>"employees",
> > >       "action"=>"update", "id"=>"29955"} permitted: false>
> > >
> > > params[:employee]
> > >       => {"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"1", "name"=>"test",
> > >       "start_day_of_the_week"=>"Monday", “sw_id"=>"2"},
> > >       "1"=>{"name"=>"test2", "start_day_of_the_week"=>"Monday",
> > >       “sw_id"=>"3"}}} permitted: false>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return if params[:employee].present? &&
params[:employee][:emp_attributes].values.any?{|m| m.key?("_destroy")}
```